# Leaflet Polygon with 6 or more latlon points

Tags: leaflet, polygon

Helo! I have 8 points and I need to draw a polygon, but if I pass the points randomly, the lines cross as shown in the image below. I needed to make a closed polygon without crossing lines.

`var latlngs`

`var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet has no idea what the "intended" order of points is.  While you may have in your mind that you want a relatively convex shape crafted from x number of points, you need to be the one to order them properly so that the shape you intend is drawn as you intend it.

If you are facing a problem where you have an unsorted array of points, and you need to draw the most convex shape around those points that you can, this is a classic convex hull problem.  [TurfJS has a convex function you can use](https://turfjs.org/docs/#convex) for that.  There's also a [concave hull](https://turfjs.org/docs/#concave) function there if that's what you need.